# Keeping collection of objects ordered by an attribute

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures

I have a class Node, where it has some values that make it unique (x and y) and also an attribute "cost".

I want to keep a collection of Nodes inside a data structure, such as a red black tree. The idea is that the node with the lowest cost should be the first one in the tree, and when I insert a new node into the tree I would want it to be placed in sorted order (like in log n time)

The idea is that the nodes are identified by x and y and so I am hashing them with a tuple of those two values for searching them in a set and comparing them (__eq__). But for sorting I just want to look at the cost attribute, but since the cost may not be unique for two nodes, I can't use that as a key for a dictionary.

This can mean I might need two structures, one for searching by x and y and the other one to keep them sorted and have both operations be fast (time matters).

I've read about ordereddict but I don't think it can achieve what I want with that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Examples would be welcome...

Comment: Sure sounds like a [priority queue](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/priority-queue-in-python/) to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Jim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56778/jim-mischel) suggested, I did indeed want to use a priority queue, but I could not find what I want. Turns out python does have a heapq package which manipulates lists to make heaps. This alongside defining __lt__ on the Node class did exactly what I wanted.